# How to extract specific data and its values from a text file using python

Tags: python, excel

How to extract specific data from a text file and export the text and the values displayed next to it to excel. Right now I can export the list of data I want, but not sure how to get the values displayed next to the text. The text file has information like this:

```
Total Preprocessing Time:           231.225
Total Find Global Min Max Time:     151.913
Total Setup Geometry Time:          0.016
Total Other time:               15.180
Total Time:                 720.881
```

I want to capture the time next to the text and export to excel. 
I've used some of the examples given in this website to extract the specific data I want and it worked.

```
infile = r"D:\GPU\App1.log"
important = []
keep_phrases = ["Total Preprocessing Time:",
               "Total Find Global Min Max Time:"
               "Total Setup Geometry Time:",
               "Total Other time:",
               "Total Time:"]

with open(infile) as f:
    for line in f:
        for phrase in keep_phrases:
            if phrase in line:
                important.append(line)
                break
print(important)
```

#### To write data to csv file in columns and rows from a list in python.

```
infile = open('output.csv', 'w')
for row in keep_phrases:
    for column in row:
        infile.write("%s" % column)
    infile.write('\n')
infile.close()
```

This is how it exported the text in excel.

```
Total Preprocessing Time:
Total Find Global Min Max Time:
Total Setup Geometry Time:
Total Other time:
Total Time:
```

Comment: Try using xlrd (https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/).

Comment: shouldn't you loop `important` and not `keep_phrases`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It works now. Thank you so much :)